# .NET version of elasticsearch?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Is anyone aware of a .NET port of elasticsearch that has been implemented?  We have found a .NET client (easy enough to create on our own), but not the server.

Comment: Why does it matter?  It's a self-contained, it shouldn't matter how it's implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but why would you want a .net version of the server?

It is a standalone server, so it doesn't matter what language it is written in.

ElasticSearch uses the Lucene libraries, which are in Java, so not only would you have to rewrite ElasticSearch, you'd also have to rewrite Lucene.

Comment: @John: You don't need a LAMP stack, elasticsearch runs on Windows just fine.

Comment: @DrTech but there is Lucene.net so the OP needs only to implement ES.net ;)